# Add variables in script source Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=.......&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

I want to add `&libraries=geometry` into the script above, how describe it?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=.......&sensor=false&libraries=places&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=.......&sensor=false&libraries[]=places&libraries[]=geometry"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries), you should give multiple libraries comma-separated:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=.......&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot specify to variables with the same name, the post/get script will only handle one of those
I suggest you replace 'libraries=places&libraries=geometry' with 'libraries=places,geometry' and see how that works for you.